# Which is more optimal for OpenGL ES -- transforming with modelview calls, or animation?

Tags: java, android, animation, opengl-es

In general, is it more performance optimal to draw 2D transformations with OpenGL ES directly (using a call to modelview I guess), or via animation (binding a series of different textures from the same texture atlas)?

My hunch is that its more optimal to stick with the same texture and transform it with OpenGL ES, but I'm not sure enough to estimate how many animations I need, so I need to know if and why it would be more optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create something like a spritesheet animation or just move an object?

For example, in my game, I have a car riding on a road. I have four textures to simulate the spinning wheels. I have created VBOs in GPU and just keep changing the texture handler, using the same vertex. I move the car using modelview matrix.

What improves performance is to use VBOs in the GPU, and avoid binding vertex arrays every frame.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you intend exactly to implement the transformations with animated textures.  But in general, yes, doing 2D transformations directly (with a vertex shader, I presume) is much more efficient.  With an animated texture, you'd pay the bandwidth cost of uploading the entire set of textures, as well as increased texture cache pressure from a larger working set of textures.  2D transformation, on the other hand, is likely only a shader uniform update per-frame.